# How to efficiently display array elements using AJAX and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've retrieved data (6 users) from an API using AJAX, and I want to display the names and avatars of each user using only JavaScript. The problem is that when I when I run the code, it displays 6 copies of the same user and I don't know why.

I've already played around with $.each and other methods, but they don't seem to work.

```
var items = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)

userData = items.data;

for (var i = 0; i < userData.length; i++){
  $("body").append("<div class = 'container'> " + "<div class = 'user'> " + "<div class = 'profile_picture'>" + "<img>" + "</img>" + "</div>" + "<div class = 'name'>" + "<h1>"+ "</h1>" + "</div>" + "</div>" + "</div>")

  imgEl = $("img")
  h1El = $("h1")

  $(imgEl).attr("src", userData[i].avatar)
  $(h1El).text(userData[i].first_name + " " + userData[i].last_name)   
}
```

I expected that userData[i] would loop through the array, but it just shows the last element.

Comment: You are appending multiple containers, but you are changing `$('img')` and `$('h1')` which are global selectors, and will be changing all of those elements on the page.  Not just the last one appended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is due to your global `$('img')` and `$('h1')` selectors updating all the images and h1s on the page to be the last one.  You need to update only the last one appended.

Another approach to solving this issue though would be to separate your html from your javascript, to more closely follow the separation of concerns practice.  Using an html template, you can reuse it and inject the data that you want for each entry fairly easily.

```js
var userData = [
  {
    avatar: 'https://www.fakeurl.com/photo1.png',
    first_name: 'Jake',
    last_name: 'Blane'
  },{
    avatar: 'https://www.fakeurl.com/photo2.png',
    first_name: 'Jill',
    last_name: 'White'
  }
];

var userTemplate = $('#userTemplate').html();

$(document.body).append(
  userData.map( user => {
    return userTemplate
      .replace( '%USER_AVATAR%', user.avatar )
      .replace( '%USER_LABEL%', `${user.first_name} ${user.last_name}` )
  } )
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<template id="userTemplate">
  <div class = 'container'>
    <div class = 'user'>
      <div class = 'profile_picture'>
        <img src = '%USER_AVATAR%' >
      </div>
      <div class = 'name'>
        <h1>%USER_LABEL%</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: That is awesome, never though of doing it this way. Are you just storing the template inside a hidden element somewhere on the page?

Comment: `<template>` is a great new html5 feature but not thouroughly supported by all browsers yet (IE is still not treating it properly ...).

Comment: "is still not" will never. IE isn't receiving any more feature updates.

Comment: `<script type="text/html">` works just as well for IE support in place of the `<template>` @cars10m  And if we're talking about IE support, the template literals would also have to be replaced with string concatenation

Comment: Yes, very true, and the arrow-function syntax `map(u=>...)` I used, would also not be working. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

You can do it also without setting up a template, like shown below:

```js
var userData = [
 {avatar: 'https://via.placeholder.com/100/ffb000',first_name:'Jake',last_name:'Blane'},
 {avatar: 'https://via.placeholder.com/100/da0800',first_name:'Jill',last_name:'White'}];

$('body').append(userData.map(u=>
  "<div class = 'container'><div class='user'><div class='profile_picture'><img src='"
  +u.avatar+"' /></div><div class = 'name'><h1>"
  +u.first_name+' '+u.last_name+"</h1></div></div></div>").join("\n"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I am a big fan of jquery and have been using it for a long time but in this case you can achieve the same thing very easily without by replacing

```
$('body').append( <html_code ...> )
```

with:

```
document.querySelector('body').innerHTML += <htm_code ...>
```

The template method, as shown by @Taplar in this thread is to be preferred, when things get a bit more complex, as they will be easier to maintain then.

Comment: I downvoted because of your use of `with` which has been deprecated for some time now. Please remove it; we don't need to tell new developers about it, especially since it doesn't exist in strict mode anyways.

Comment: Right, yes, that is something I can deal with. Especially, as I don't really need it in this case anyway. Thanks!